# Are all the characters from the previous Fire Emblem games available?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I noticed that some cool old characters such as [Lyn](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Lyndis) and Roy are around, but I was wondering if [Hector](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Hector) and [Will](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Wil) are in the game as well.

**In short, is there a list of all the characters programmed into the game that are available for recruitment?**

Comment: @Vemonus I just want to know who is available now, to see if the characters I want are in the game or not :) That's why I bolded that portion of my question, but I'll remove the last sentence if it helps make it clearer.

Comment: [here you go](https://www.reddit.com/r/FireEmblemHeroes/comments/5rlu1m/list_of_characters_available_rarity/)

Comment: @KevinL add your comment as an answer and somewhat more expansive, then it can be accepted by the OP

Comment: @Wouter i am too lazy to do that, you can go ahead and flesh it out as an answer though

Comment: @KevinL sure that would help answer this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment there is an expansive list on reddit ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FireEmblemHeroes/comments/5rlu1m/list_of_characters_available_rarity/)).

Of course this list will be longer in the future because I expect that they will add more heroes in future updates.

To answer about the specific heroes: Hector is in the game but Will isn't as of now, but this can change in the future